# Fields that show up locally on SAP Crystal Reports develper are missing when run on server using SAP BO

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

I have a simple report in Crystal to develop. The business sends me the SQL, I copy and paste, and create 1 prompt. Easy. It's actually a duplicate of an existing report, but the join criteria is modified a bit to look at a different set of purchase orders.

So when I run my new report locally where I developed it, in SAP Crystal Reports developer, it runs perfectly and looks the way it needs to: 9 columns w/headers, all displaying data for each row.

When I run that same report in SAP Business Objects on the web (which is where the business runs it), 3 of the the 9 columns have the header but no data.

I originally thought it was because I simply took the existing report, updated the SQL, and did a "save as"... I thought something may have gotten wonky in the metadata (it's happened before). So I built it from scratch and still the same problem. I've also tried just pulling on only those fields. Shows up in developer, but not on the web.

Here's what it looks like in developer for me locally:
[image: locally]

And here's what it looks like on the web:
[image: Web]

Anyone have any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: @bogl - Just edited for clarity. Sorry, too far in the weeds with this one.

Comment: My best guess is that you are using one data source when you run locally and another when its deployed.  Is it possible that the data source/database when you deploy the CR does not contain the missing values? Can you run the query in SSMS and make sure the values exist?